# How can I display 20-25 lines of text when I click on an image in a gridview?

Tags: android

I have about 50 images with in a grid view within my Android app. When I click on an image, I want the description of that image to be displayed.

This is the code I have so far:

```
public class HarryActivity extends Activity
     {    
    //---the images to display---
    Integer[] imageIDs = {
            R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic2,
            R.drawable.pic3,
            R.drawable.pic4,
            R.drawable.pic5,
            R.drawable.pic6,
            R.drawable.pic7                    
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, 
            View v, int position, long id) 
            {                
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });        
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        private Context context;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
        {
            context = c;
        }

        //---returns the number of images---
        public int getCount() {
            return imageIDs.length;
        }

        //---returns the ID of an item--- 
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //---returns an ImageView view---
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
            return imageView;
        }
    }    
}
```

How can I add this functionality to my Android app?

Comment: i welcome some suggestions how to implement this in the best way also

Comment: Have you looked at the Android Developer site? The have a tutorial on how to create Galleries. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Comment: yes i tried but i do not want a little toast mesage but the text of 20 -25 lines

Comment: Could you add some code for what you have so far?

Comment: and that to I want only gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a dialog box to display the details ,extend the alert dialog box , or you can define a textview in UI make it invisible and on click of image make it visible.

Comment: can any one provide how to display the different types of alerts when clicked on the images

Comment: WARNING: The link above was displayed as an "Attack Page".  Do not click it.

Comment: I am really sorry for that my site got infected with some malware trying to remove it.